# Is there a quick way to check if a function $h(x)$ can be generated as a composition of other functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, function-and-relation-composition

Given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, infinitely many compositions can be generated. For example we can look at the following two functions:

$$f(x) = 2x$$

$$g(x) = x+1$$

There is a subspace of all functions that can be generated such as the following examples:

$$(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = 2x+1$$

$$(g\circ f\circ f)(x) = 4x+1$$

$$(f\circ f\circ f\circ g\circ g\circ f)(x) = 16x+16$$

Is there a way to see if functions fall into this space? For the above example, it is easy to see that any function following

$$h(x) = 2^{c_1}*x+{c_2}$$

can be generated, but a function such as

$$h(x) = x$$

can never be generated from $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Is there a way to generalize this to any two functions in order to see what functions can/cannot be generated?

Comment: Why the linear algebra and number theory tags?

Comment: I have an intuitive feeling there may be a way to relate this to the Halting Problem.

Comment: I doubt the set described is a subspace.

Comment: Are we strictly talking about polynomial functions here?

Comment: The question requires a fundamental clarification - which class of functions are considered as building material, is there some restriction on generation, whether a function inverse to a given one is allowed, an identical function, etc.

Comment: Without some restrictions this is hard.  Take $f$ defined whole numbers with $f(x)=x/2$ on evens, $f(x)=3x+1$ on odds > 1 and $f(1)=0$.  Let $g(x)=x$.  Now does $h(x)=0$ live in the set of compositions?  This is Collatz Conjecture, and it's unsolved.

Comment: @T.J.Gaffney, I think the Collatz conjecture just says "for each $x$, there is some composition $h$ such that $h(x) = 0$". Your version would be "there is some $t$ such that every number reaches $1$ after time $t$", which isn't true. If you instead let $g$ be a constant $k$, then the Collatz conjecture is "is $h(x) = 0$ in the set of compositions for every choice of $k$"?

Comment: I think some reasonable interpretations of this question include "consider the monoid of polynomials under composition. Is there any classification of the $2$-generated submonoids?" where some variations include taking the coefficients to be in any (semi)ring you like eg the (nonnegative) integers/rationals/reals/complex numbers. Or also, you might consider rational functions instead of polynomials. I can't find much about any of these questions after a quick search though. Are any of those interpretations what you're interested in, OP? Welcome to MSE by the way :)